# What is the updated theme of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

It seems that our current wordpress Theme is 4 years old. It first needs to be replaced with a more up to date developer theme. Can anyone help me to find one and share the link so I review and integrate it? i tried a lot but not able to find any.

Answer (score 0):

There are some questions you should check,
1) Is your theme is premium? if not than 
2) Is this uploaded to wordpress directory ? Or 
3) You have custom built this ??

If you answer is 3 than,
The custom theme can not be updated directly , if you want to update than you can update some wordpress functions which are depreciated so this should be a manual process.

IF your answer is 1 or 2 you can easily find the updated version but only if available.

Hope this information is enough, if want any other guidance feel free to ask.
Thanks,

Comment: Hi Mukesh, My theme is not premium i just need a basic framework with no styling, I have various choices but i am very much confused. I want to know which basic framework will be the best which  can use as a wordpress theme..

Comment: I am not sure what you want exactly , please explain in brief so i can help.

Comment: All you want to replace the content and data with your existing theme to some modern theme in market?

Answer (score 0):

From what you say I understand you want a starter theme which you can develop further to suit your needs. The most widely used starter theme is [Underscores](http://underscores.me/). If you have some money to spare a premium framework like [Genesis](http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis/) gives more possibilities. For more options just Google for "wordpress starter theme".